# google sheet apps script how duplicate tab with same permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im using this script to duplicate and rename a template sheet

```
function duplicate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastTabName = ss.getSheets().pop().getSheetName();  // Modified
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp').copyTo(ss);

  // Duplica Template
  sheet.setName(isNaN(lastTabName) ? 1 : Number(lastTabName) + 1);  // Modified
  sheet.getRange("G2").setValue(Number(lastTabName) + 1 );

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);    
}
```

In that template sheet I have cell H1 protected, that only im available to edit, but not all other editors of the spreadsheet, also range B10:C136 the same (im only allowed to edit)

How can I modify that script, so when I run it, the template duplicates with the same protections, and the same condition that im the only one to be able to edit those ranges?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
function duplicate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastTabName = ss.getSheets().pop().getSheetName();  // Modified
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp')
  var newSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(ss);
  var protections = templateSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  // Duplicate Template
  newSheet.setName(isNaN(lastTabName) ? 1 : Number(lastTabName) + 1);  // Modified
  newSheet.getRange("G2").setValue(Number(lastTabName) + 1 );

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    var protectedRange = protection.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var newProtection = newSheet.getRange(protectedRange).protect();
  }

  ss.setActiveSheet(newSheet);  
}
```

Please feel free to explore more examples from this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).

Comment: Hi, thank for that ... it works, my problem is that if the editor runs the script, then the permissions are not only to allow me, he is also allowed to edit those cells, I don't know if there is a way to fix it